# Match string to enumeration?

Tags: c#

I am using a 3rd party DLL which expects an enumeration called 'DaysOfWeek' in the method signature.

I am allowing my users to select the day of week from a ComboBox, but I end up with a string.

How can I match my string to the appropriate enumeration property?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Some solutions might be more elegant than others, but this seems like a straightforward problem of mapping one to the other.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), yourStringValue, true);
```

Note: This will launch an exception if the string is not convertible to the enum. Last parameter is for case insensitive search.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the following to convert a string to an enum:

```
 DaysOfWeek value = (DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse( typeof(DaysOfWeek), enumAsString );
```

You can also use the case-insensitive overload if users may type in theor own values:

```
 DaysOfWeek value = (DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse( typeof(DaysOfWeek), enumAsString, true );
```

Comment: I know you just did the 2nd part as an example of how to do it, but why would you ever need the user to type in the value of an enumerated type if you could just make a dropdown for instant validation?

Comment: Perhaps in the case where you're not driving it from a combo box, but maybe from a command line parameter. I appreciate it's not the specific question posed, but the information was certainly useful in my case!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the combo box contains the enumeration names.

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();

cb.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(DaysOfWeek));

(DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), cb.SelectedText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for cross-referencing, but in my anser here theres a helper class called `EnumPair<T>`
That you could use to fill the ComboBox and have the value of the enum back to use further on.

using this three lines will fill the comboBox correctly for you:

```
cbo.DataSource = EnumPair<TEnum>.GetValuePairList();
cbo.ValueMember = EnumPair<TEnum>.ValueMember;
cbo.DisplayMember = EnumPair<TEnum>.DisplayMember;
```

Here is the original [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929020/using-windows-forms-combo-box-with-listkeyvaluepairuserenum-string-as-datasou/1929217#1929217)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) to convert the string to the actual Enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parse method on the Enum static type.

```
DaysOfWeek day = (DaysOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DaysOfWeek), (string)dropDownList.SelectedItem);
```

Alternatively, you can populate the drop-down-list with enum values directly and avoid the conversion issues entirely.

```
    // Populate combobox.
    foreach (DaysOfWeek day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfWeek)))
    {
        daysOfWeekCombo.Items.Add(day);
    }
    // Read combobox.
    DaysOfWeek day = (DaysOfWeek)daysOfWeekCombo.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that looks something like this:

```
public class DayOfWeekComboBoxItem
{
   public string Day{get;set;}
   public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek{get;set;}

   public override ToString()
   {
      return this.Date;
   }
}
```

Then bind your combo box to a collection of these items. Then you can cast the SelectedItem in the combo box to an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are populating your ComboBox from the DaysOfWeek enum:

```
this.comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek));
```

Then you can get the enum value from the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox:

```
DayOfWeek selected = (DayOfWeek)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other (correct and built-in) suggestions, there is also an interesting Third-Party `Enum<T>` class that makes working with enums much more nice:

http://blog.logrythmik.com/post/Better-Enum-Parsing-using-Strongly-Typed-Generics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a list of name/value pairs, where the value is your enum.
A bit more work, but will make it easier to support localization down the line if you ever need it.  Here's one way:

```
static IList<KeyValuePair<string, DayOfWeek>> GetDayOfWeekBindingList()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, DayOfWeek>> dayOfWeekList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, DayOfWeek>>();

    foreach (int day in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
    {
        string dayName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[day];
        dayOfWeekList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, DayOfWeek>(dayName, (DayOfWeek)day));
    }
    return dayOfWeekList;
}

private void BindDayOfWeekComboBox()
{
    dayOfWeekComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
    dayOfWeekComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
    dayOfWeekComboBox.DataSource = GetDayOfWeekBindingList();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindDayOfWeekComboBox();
    ...
}
```

You can then access the day of week as:

```
    (DayOfWeek) dayOfWeekComboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would prefer. If parsing got failed, it need to be handled.

```
// this will hold parsed value
DaysOfWeek daySelected;

// 'toMatch' is the string to be parsed or checked

if (Enum.TryParse(toMatch, out daySelected) && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DaysOfWeek), daySelected))
{
    // parsed success, use 'daySelected'

}
else
{
    // parsed failed

}
```